# Get Raw Style Sheets as string in js?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to import the Raw sass in js as string. Without using node. Is there any way to get the content in the scss/sass/css as a variable?

I have tried with `getComputedStyles` but that just shows the valid properties. Is there a "hacky" way to read this out?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking -- are you asking how to find the CSS rules that you've written which don't match *any* elements on the page? And why are you trying to get the CSS rules in JavaScript? Adding an element style from JavaScript will overwrite any rules set in the CSS, so there's really no need to do this. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to readout the raw css for testing things and add some Modyfied css actions. I want to definde new Properties and start some js actions wenn they are called in css. It sounds strange but i think in my case its the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky to fully understand your requirement, I assume you would like to import SASS and use it as CSS - therefore you'll need to do your own thing with the rules you're importing?

You can indeed edit the Stylesheets and with some clever code - you can produce live or new CSS on the fly:

Here's an example from this page:

```
document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[0].cssText
".wmd-snippet-button span { background-position: 0px 0px; }"
```

Therefore you can iterate and read all your implemented CSS, or create new nodes

`styleSheets` in an array of `CSSStyleSheet` instances.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I also read the style sheet with this method or just edit / overwrite?

Comment: The above example shows reading the CSS within a block. I feel I missed your question though, could you rephrase it?